# How can i reference the AspNetUser table id column from my class that is storing a foreign key in userId (.net 4.5)

Tags: c#, sql

I'm slightly confused. I'm building my .net project using code first.
I've got a class called School.cs and in there I reference

```
[ForeignKey("User")]
public string UserId { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Where i'm trying to set UserId as a foreign key to the AspNetUser id column.

My context classes are set up with an IdentityDb.cs file and SchoolContext.cs file.

```
       public class IdentityDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public IdentityDb()
                : base("SchoolContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {
            }


          public virtual ICollection<School> Schools { get; set; } 


            public static IdentityDb Create()
            {
                return new IdentityDb();
            }
        }
```

And

```
 public SchoolContext() : base ("SchoolContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        }

    }
```

The issue I have is that when I want to add a school i'm getting the error message:

INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

And it errors out when trying to save to the db.

Because I'm doing this code first the database is generated automatically based on my classes and what I've noticed is in the db the foreign key constraint is set as:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Schools_dbo.ApplicationUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ApplicationUsers] ([Id])
```

And it's that first part "FK_dbo.Schools_dbo.ApplicationUsers_UserId" where if i'm right there is actually no UserId column in AspNetUsers which I think is the problem.

I've gone back to my school class to change the foreign key property to just "Id"

```
[ForeignKey("User")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

But that still produced an error.

In the create method the code looks like:

```
 school.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
 Debug.WriteLine(school.UserId);
 db.Schools.Add(school);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

And school.UserId prints to console with the appropriate value but it errors out at db.Schools.Add(school).

Could do with some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure UserId you're using exist in AspNetUsers table?

Comment: Hi @Jaffal. It doesn't. The primary key for AspNetUser is id. But when the table is created based on my school class it is looking for AspNetUser userId.

Comment: not its not its telling you that the value in UserId which is a column you have in Schools table doesn't exist in the Id column in AspNetuser table.

Try to read more about EntityFramework code first and it's Fluent API or Data Annotation Attributes

Comment: Hi @Jaffal. That's correct. So what I did is I changed the public string in School class from UserId to Id but that still didn't map correctly.

Comment: can you sure your Table structures in images showing the record of the user Id in the AspNetUser table

Comment: Hi. Are you sure that at the moment you’re adding a record to the Schools table with say FK UserId == “sample_user_id” such user with id == “sample_user_id” actually exists in AspNetUser table?
Because I’ve played with your example a bit and everything seems to work smoothly if users referred by FK from Schools exists. If they don’t then I had exactly the same error as you described...
BTW does your Schools table has its own PK defined?

Comment: Hi Oleksandr. Yeah the id does exist but it's in the "Id" column of AspNetUser. But the foreign key in the db table references dbo.ApplicationUsers_UserId and there is no UserId (I don't think in ApplicationUsers) which I think is the problem. But I will keep trying! There are by the way also three "Identity" tables in the database that get created at runtime that correspond to IdentityLogin,etc from OnModelCreating but these tables are empty.

Comment: If anyone reads this i'd also like to add that how entity framework generates the db tables from code first is a bit annoying. i've got everything working but only after i had to rewrite the db tables. The first three lines of my code at the top where there is [ForeignKey("User")], string UserId, virtual ApplicationUser....results in EF creating an ApplicationUsers table in addition to AspNetUsers table. And that ApplicationUsers table doesn't appear to ever be used. And the foreign key constraint ends up being to ApplicationUsers when in fact I want it to AspNetUsers. Thx.